# How to compare three different Lists and get the differences, common?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 ArrayLists. the first list is constant and always has 7 values (Days of a week).

```java
ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add("MON");
list1.add("WED");
list1.add("THU");
list1.add("SAT");
list1.add("SUN"); The second ArrayList is a collection of Days

ArrayList<String> list2 = DBmanager.getList2();

// list2 = {"MON", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT" }
```

The 3rd ArryList is also a collection of Days

```java
ArrayList<String> list3 = DBmanager.getList3();

// list3 = {"MON", "TUE", "THU", "SAT" }
```

Now, I have to compare all 3. Now I need to record the comparison result in  ArrayLists like

```
MissinginList1VsList2List3  for example ans should be 
[FRI:list2,TUE:list3] because list1 does not have fri and tue
MissinginList2VsList1List3 MissinginList3VsList1List2
NewinList1VsList2List3 NewinList2VsList1List3 NewinList3VsList1List2
commoninList1List2List3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at `Collections.retainAll` and `Collections.removeAll` Incidentally, your code would be sounder using `java.time.DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question so you can try like this for Example:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("MON");
list1.add("WED");
list1.add("THU");
list1.add("SAT");
list1.add("SUN");

ArrayList<String> list2 = DBmanager.getList2();
// Assuming list2 = {"MON", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT" }

ArrayList<String> list3 = DBmanager.getList3();
// Assuming list3 = {"MON", "TUE", "THU", "SAT" }
```

then you can search in the Lists like them:

```
ArrayList<String> missingInList1VsList2List3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> missingInList2VsList1List3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> missingInList3VsList1List2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> newInList1VsList2List3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> newInList2VsList1List3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> newInList3VsList1List2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> commonInList2List3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Comparing list1 with list2 and list3
for (String day : list2) {
    if (!list1.contains(day)) {
        missingInList1VsList2List3.add(day);
    } else {
        commonInList2List3.add(day);
    }
}

for (String day : list3) {
    if (!list1.contains(day)) {
        missingInList1VsList2List3.add(day);
    } else {
        commonInList2List3.add(day);
    }
}

//Comparing list2 with list1 and list3
for (String day : list1) {
    if (!list2.contains(day)) {
        missingInList2VsList1List3.add(day);
    }
}

for (String day : list3) {
    if (!list2.contains(day)) {
        missingInList2VsList1List3.add(day);
    }
}

// Comparing list3 with list1 and list2
for (String day : list1) {
    if (!list3.contains(day)) {
        missingInList3VsList1List2.add(day);
    }
}

for (String day : list2) {
    if (!list3.contains(day)) {
        missingInList3VsList1List2.add(day);
    }
}

// Find new days in list1, list2, and list3
for (String day : list1) {
    if (!list2.contains(day) && !list3.contains(day)) {
        newInList1VsList2List3.add(day);
    }
}

for (String day : list2) {
    if (!list1.contains(day) && !list3.contains(day)) {
        newInList2VsList1List3.add(day);
    }
}

for (String day : list3) {
    if (!list1.contains(day) && !list2.contains(day)) {
        newInList3VsList1List2.add(day);
    }
}
```

if you want to output them:

```
System.out.println("Missing in list1 vs list2 and list3: " + missingInList1VsList2List3);
System.out.println("Missing in list2 vs list1 and list3: " + missingInList2VsList1List3);
System.out.println("Missing in list3 vs list1 and list2: " + missingInList3VsList1List2);
System.out.println("New in list1 vs list2 and list3: " + newInList1VsList2List3);
System.out.println("New in list2 vs list1 and list3: " + newInList2VsList1List3);
System.out.println("New in list3 vs list1 and list2: " + newInList3VsList1List2);
System.out.println("Common in list2 and list3: " + commonInList2List3);
```

Comment: how to find common in list1list2list3

Comment: how to find common in list1list2list3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` methods of `Collection`.

```java
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> one = List.of("MON", "WED", "THU", "SAT", "SUN");
        List<String> two = List.of("MON", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT");
        List<String> three = List.of("MON", "TUE", "THU", "SAT");

        String oneName = "list1";
        String twoName = "list2";
        String threeName = "list3";

        System.out.println(oneName + ": " + one);
        System.out.println(twoName + ": " + two);
        System.out.println(threeName + ": " + three);

        System.out.println();

        print(one, oneName, two, twoName, three, threeName);
    }

    public static void print(List<String> one, String oneName,
                             List<String> two, String twoName,
                             List<String> three, String threeName) {
        printMissing(one, oneName, two, twoName, three, threeName);
        printMissing(two, twoName, one, oneName, three, threeName);
        printMissing(three, threeName, one, oneName, two, twoName);

        printNew(one, oneName, two, twoName, three, threeName);
        printNew(two, twoName, one, oneName, three, threeName);
        printNew(three, threeName, one, oneName, two, twoName);

        printCommon(three, threeName, one, oneName, two, twoName);
    }

    private static void printMissing(List<String> one, String oneName,
                                     List<String> two, String twoName,
                                     List<String> three, String threeName) {
        print("Missing", oneName, twoName, threeName, () -> {
            List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(two);
            res.addAll(three);
            res.removeAll(one);
            return res;
        });
    }

    private static void printNew(List<String> one, String oneName,
                                 List<String> two, String twoName,
                                 List<String> three, String threeName) {
        print("New", oneName, twoName, threeName, () -> {
            List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(one);
            res.removeAll(two);
            res.removeAll(three);
            return res;
        });
    }

    private static void printCommon(List<String> one, String oneName,
                                    List<String> two, String twoName,
                                    List<String> three, String threeName) {
        print("Common", oneName, twoName, threeName, () -> {
            List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(one);
            res.retainAll(two);
            res.retainAll(three);
            return res;
        });
    }

    private static void print(String action,
                              String oneName,
                              String twoName,
                              String threeName,
                              Supplier<List<String>> result) {
        List<String> res = result.get();

        if (!res.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.format("%s in %s vs %s and %s: %s\n",
                              action, oneName, twoName, threeName, res);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
list1: [MON, WED, THU, SAT, SUN]
list2: [MON, WED, THU, FRI, SAT]
list3: [MON, TUE, THU, SAT]

Missing in list1 vs list2 and list3: [FRI, TUE]
Missing in list2 vs list1 and list3: [SUN, TUE]
Missing in list3 vs list1 and list2: [WED, SUN, WED, FRI]
New in list1 vs list2 and list3: [SUN]
New in list2 vs list1 and list3: [FRI]
New in list3 vs list1 and list2: [TUE]
Common in list3 vs list1 and list2: [MON, THU, SAT]
```